# How to add Transloco translation files in production mode?

Tags: transloco

I got an error when running my app in IIS: `myServer/assets/i18n/de.json not found`. How to add the Transloco translation files in production mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a fullstop to ./assets/i18n in transloco-root.module.ts fixed my problem.

```
getTranslation(lang: string) {
    return this.http.get<Translation>(`./assets/i18n/${lang}.json`);}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, this doesn't work for me.